# Page Break PHP Loop

Tags: php

i have Code Like this , i want add footer after mods 3, and if this Not modulus 3

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i%3==0){
        echo "Header";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo $i."<br>";
}
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
Header
0
1
2
footer
Header
3
4
5
footer
Header
6
7
8
footer
Header
9
10
footer
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i using for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
            if($i%3==0){
                echo "Header";
                echo "<br>";
            }
            echo $i."<br>";
            echo "footer";
        } but thas not Work

Comment: i want add header and footer after 3 rows , ??? iam New On php

Comment: From Review: Please just EDIT your question and add the code you have posted in your comment. Avoid posting comments to your own question when possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tryout this answer

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "Header". "<br>";
    }
    echo $i . "<br>";
    if (($i + 1) % 3 == 0 || $i==10) {
        echo "Footer". "<br>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split values into chunks and process each chunk as required:

```
$values = range(0, 10);
$chunks = array_chunk($values, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo 'Header<br />' . implode('<br />', $chunk) . '<br />Footer<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
echo "Header<br/>\n";

for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i > 1 && $i < 10 && $i % 3 === 0){
        echo "footer<br/>\n";
        echo "Header<br/>\n";
    }
    echo $i."<br/>\n";
}
echo "footer<br/>\n";
```

Comment: @DanuraAditya Great, I'm glad to help. Please upvote & accept this answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code

```
 for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    if($i%3==0){
          if($i > 2){ 
              echo "footer";
              echo "<br>";
          }
          echo "Header";
          echo "<br>";
    }
    echo $i."<br>";
  }

  echo "footer";
```